# Where is brightness option in the PC version of Deadly Premonition?

Tags: pc, deadly-premonition

I have [The Director's Cut](http://store.steampowered.com/app/247660/) on PC. The "option" menu has no brightness settings, I have tried both fullscreen and windowed display modes.

settings:

[image]

the pause menu:

[image]

launcher:

[image]

Judging from [online discussions](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/943433-deadly-premonition-the-directors-cut/66196422) the brightness setting clearly exists.

Comment: Do you have DPFix installed or no?

Comment: @Vemonus: Yes I have.

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking it was a feature added by that, but if you can't find it, I'm not sure. There's not much info out there, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PC version has no brightness options, while to PS3 version does.

PS3 options menu:

[image]
[image]
[image]

PC options menu, "display setting" is absent:

[image]

[source](https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Deadly_Premonition:_The_Director%27s_Cut)